# Syntax for declaring a specific tf-nightly version in build.gradle dependencies?

Tags: tensorflow, build.gradle, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I use tensorflow object detection api to train a custom object detector, then convert it to tflite to deploy it to android.

It is quite often the case that a model trained on one nightly can not be used for inference on a newer nightly. I ran into this problem and am not sure on the syntax for requiring a specific nightly in the build.gradle dependencies.

For training, in python, I used:

```
pip install tf-nightly==2.4.0.dev20200817
```

In the build.gradle dependencies:

```
// Current build.gradle
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
// Ive tried
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.4.0.dev20200817-nightly'
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

The nightly TFLite builds for Android has only a single version (`0.0.0-nightly`) which gets updated everyday, and there is no way to pin to a specific nightly version, unfortunately.

Could you use a stable version instead for your use case? That won't cause you the same kind of problem. The nightly builds are meant to be experimental and not fully supported by nature.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is build AAR from source, based on a date you want and put binaries to your project. You can do it once and use binaries or build TFLite with your app. In this case you are able to use most resent features absent in current release and save your app from nightly regressions (I have meet some before, so fixed nightly build). To build your AAR see [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_android).
Also, if you "catch" nightly version you like you can fix it:

```
implementation ('org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly') { changing = false }
```